# jquery animate() callback double firing

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I am using jquery to add and remove css animation classes when my website is first loaded.  I am using .animate() and nested 5 deep, using another in the callback of each.  For some reason the last one is double firing and making the animation css class run twice.

I have read through the jquery docs but havent found any useful answers.  When I remove the deepest .animate() for the "expand" class, every thing else still works as expected so I am not sure what is going on and hoping someone could be able to point me in the right direction to getting this working properly.

You can view the issue at http://www.holdero.com and it is the marketing icon that slides in twice when the page is loaded.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

The jQuery

```
function slide_up_titles() {    
    $(".big_text").addClass("bigEntrance");
    $(".big_text").animate({
        opacity: 1  
    }, 1500, function(){
//animation complete
        $(".big_text").removeClass("bigEntrance");
        $(".title_caption").addClass("hatch");
        $(".title_caption").animate({
            opacity: 1  
        }, 1000, function(){
//animation complete
            $(".title_caption").removeClass("hatch");
            $(".pulsate").addClass("slideUp");
            $(".pulsate").animate({
                opacity: 1  
            }, 600, function(){
//animation complete
                $(".pulsate").removeClass("slideUp");
                $(".rotate").addClass("slideUp");
                $(".rotate").animate({
                    opacity: 1  
                }, 600, function(){
//animation complete
                    $(".rotate").removeClass("slideUp");
                    $(".expand").addClass("slideUp");
                    $(".expand").animate({
                        opacity: 1  
                    }, 600, function(){
//animation complete
                        $(".expand").removeClass("slideUp");

                    });
                });
            });
        });

    });
};
```

The HTML

```
    <div id="mainWrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col one big_pad"> 
            <p class="text-center armwrestler big_text hidden">STEVEN JAMES HOLDER</p>
            <p class="text-center title_caption hidden">Phoenix, AZ</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row full_row bg_copper ">
    <div id="mainWrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col one_third margin_bottom_mobile">
                <div class="text-center rock txt_tan scroll_design">
                    <i class="fa fa-picture-o fa-5x pulsate txt_tan hidden"></i>
                    <br /><br />
                    <h2 class="hidden pulsate">Design</h2>
                </div>         
            </div>
            <div class="col one_third margin_bottom_mobile">
                <div class="text-center rock txt_tan scroll_development">
                    <i class="fa fa-html5 fa-5x rotate hidden"></i>
                    <br /><br />
                    <h2 class="hidden rotate">Development</h2> 
                </div>                 
            </div>
            <div class="col one_third">
                <div class="text-center rock txt_tan scroll_marketing">
                    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-5x expand hidden"></i>
                    <br /><br />
                    <h2 class="hidden expand">Marketing</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have came across this myself a few times and often found that judicious use of the jQuery 'stop()' function often helps. See https://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: Thank you for the advice raynimmo.  I will study more about the stop() function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code written is deceiving!

When using a class selector for animations, each element found gets an animation call. Then each call in this code has a completion call which calls another animation. See where this is going?

`$('.expand').animate()` is called 4 times. The completion function is called 8 times. It just so happens that on one of those calls lines up just after the animation has finished its 600ms and the `slideUp` class is removed, to add `slideUp` again, consequently doubling up on the last expand slideUp animation.

---

#### Simple Fix:

Set `$('expand').animate()`'s duration parameter to around 650ms.

Comment: Hola, hola!  Thank you for your response.  Your suggestion for the simple fix did work.  You have given me some good information to research out to get a better understanding of how I can re-write this more efficiently